# Select a package from another project

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle multi-project.
In projectA I have a packageA with some classes (and some other packages, only used in projectA).

In the other projectB I want use only the packageA from projectA.

I use in projectB the following configuration:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':ProjectA')       // I understand, this is to much
}
```

In the generated JAR for projectB I now have all classes from projectA, but I don't know
how to exclude the unwanted classes (or only include the packageA with this classes).

Can somebody help me, how to configure.
Thanks

Uwe / Germany

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as @Opal said and split it out into separate projects for the dependency relationship, or if you do want to keep just 2 projects and only rely on some of the classes, then put a dependency from projectB onto a generated artifact of projectA like this:

In projectA where you are creating the artifact:

```
configurations {
    myCustom.extendsFrom runtime
}

task customJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier "custom"
    from sourceSets.main.output
    // now the packages you want to include in the artifact
    include 'com/your/domain/package1/*'
    include 'com/your/other/stuff2/*'
}

artifacts {
    myCustom customJar
}
```

and then in projectB you can depend on the generated artifact with:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':projectA', configuration: 'myCustom')
}
```

This works for any type of generated classes, so you can use "extendsFrom testRuntime" and "from sourceSets.test.output", and include paths to test classes if it's a test output relationship you want to rely on instead of main classes.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect for me. I saw similar examples before, but was not able to create the customJar task correctly. Thanks

Comment: @ula.uvula Glad I could help, it took me a while to get my head around how it works. If you're happy this works for you, can you accept the question as answered please :)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of class filtering You're trying to do isn't a good idea. Instead separate the classes/packages that need to be used in both `A` and `B` to project `C` (or `common`) and add it as a dependency to both projects.